# How to fix "ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined "

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I get an error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined" when i try to call getHistoryData() from html.

```
export class Data { 
    id : string ;
    fromTime : any ;
    toTime : any ;
    deviceType : string ;
    interval : any;
    params : string;
}
```

```
// payload : Data = {
  //   id : "00:12:4b:00:19:7b:27:7",
  //   fromTime: "1554422400000",
  //   toTime: "1554508799000" ,
  //   deviceType: "xxx",
  //   interval: "1199999",
  //   params: "temperature"
  // }

  payload : Data;

  response : any;


  generatePayload(){
    this.payload.id = "00:12:4b:00:19:7b:27:7",
    this.payload.fromTime = "1554422400000",
    this.payload.toTime = "1554508799000",
    this.payload.deviceType = 'xxx' , 
    this.payload.interval = 1000 ,
    this.payload.params = this.selectedParameter
  }

  getHistoryData(){
    this.generatePayload()
     this.historyDataService.getHistoryData(this.payload)
           .subscribe((data) => this.response = data)
  }
```

works when i assign the values of payload object directly as shown in the commented code, but when i try to assign the data through a function it throws an error.

Comment: Please reproduce your issue on stackblitz.

Comment: Need to Instantiate `this.payload` as an object as you are only defining a type

Comment: You just need to instantiate the object.  Ex:   `payload : Data = new Data( ); `.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to initialise your `payload` property with an object before you assign it with any values.

```
payload : Data = {
  id : undefined,
  fromTime: undefined,
  toTime: undefined ,
  deviceType: undefined,
  interval: undefined,
  params: undefined
};

generatePayload(){
  this.payload.id = "00:12:4b:00:19:7b:27:7",
  this.payload.fromTime = "1554422400000",
  this.payload.toTime = "1554508799000",
  this.payload.deviceType = 'xxx' , 
  this.payload.interval = 1000 ,
  this.payload.params = this.selectedParameter
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to instantiate `this.payload` as an object (being typescript, an object of the correct shape) as you are only defining a type. Simply try using the new syntax to instantiate `this.payload` as `Data`.

```
 public payload: Data;

  generatePayload()
  {
    this.payload = new Data(); // will define an object with correct keys.

    this.payload.id = "00:12:4b:00:19:7b:27:7",
    this.payload.fromTime = "1554422400000",
    this.payload.toTime = "1554508799000",
    this.payload.deviceType = 'xxx' , 
    this.payload.interval = 1000 ,
    this.payload.params = this.selectedParameter
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Because when you do `payload: Data =` you are assigning the full object. In the function you already expect the `payload` property to exist with an object value but since you have only named the property it will be undefined. Be sure to define an initial value for your property, eg `payload : Data = {};` and then the assignment will work as expected.

Comment: This will result in 'type {} is not assignable to Data, property x, y, z is missing'.